# 3D screen for working with non 3D apps

Tags: laptop

I'm planning on purchasing a new laptop from Dell - they've a good special offer on 3D screen + glasses. I wonder if 3D screen will make any difference when working with non 3D app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [120hz in 2D, what's the point?](http://superuser.com/questions/374976/120hz-in-2d-whats-the-point)

Answer (score 2):

None whatsoever.

Comment: Cheers. Would you recommend to purchase BlueRay with 3D screen? is 3D stuff coming on BlueRays mainly?

Comment: There's two use-cases for the 3D in that laptop, one is indeed for 3D Blu-Rays, the other is for 3D games, there's increasing numbers of games that support 3D right out of the box.

Comment: By the way, here's a nice report on the GPU in that laptop; http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-555M.41933.0.html

Comment: Assuming the display is capable of 120Hz, then [there are benefits](http://superuser.com/q/374976/494) to using the display for 2D.